# How to pass in parameter of a type of class when instantiating new objects?

Tags: java

Let's say I created a class named 'grade' and an array of type grade of length 32. What kind of data-type can I use as the second parameter in the method below to execute the desired code?

```
grade[] studentGrades = new grade[32];

public static void populateArray(grade[] list, ????? grade){
        for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++){
            // grade here should call the default construcor of the grade class
            list[index] = new grade(); 
        } //end of for loop
    } //end of populateArray
```

Comment: If `grade` is already a class, there should be no second parameter.

Comment: Do you intend to pass in names for subclasses of grade?

Comment: Thanks. I figured out my issue. The method needs a throws FileNotFoundException statement.

Comment: FileNotFoundExceptions? Clearly a case of posting too little information / the wrong question? :)

Comment: Nah, I got the answer I was looking for and it was correct. The application of my method is what was giving the FileNotFoundException. So, my statement (not a coded statement) about the FileNotFoundException was too little information for the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second parameter. The `new grade()` call instantiates a new grade object using a constructor which needs no parameter (the default one if no other constructor is available with that signature.

By the way, [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) expects classes to have capitalized names and variables to have not capitalized names.

Your code should look something like this

```
Grade[] studentGrades = new Grade[32];

public void populateArray(Grade[] list){
        for(int index = 0; index < list.length; index++){
            // grade here should call the default construcor of the grade class
            list[index] = new Grade();
        } //end of for loop
    } //end of populateArray
```